# Django - is it possible to quickly code this query through Django's models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these models set up in Django:

```
class SourceBusiness(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...(other fields)

class ResultBusiness(models.Model):
    sourcebusiness = models.ForeignKey(SourceBusiness)
    ...(other fields)
```

I want to get a list of distinct sources for which objects exist in the ResultBusiness table.  For example, for the following data,

```
a = SourceBusiness(source="A")
a1 = SourceBusiness(source="A")
b = SourceBusiness(source="B")
c = SourceBusiness(source="C")

x = ResultBusiness(sourcebusiness=a)
y = ResultBusiness(sourcebusiness=a1)
z = ResultBusiness(sourcebusiness=c)
```

I want to find that ResultBusinesses exist for sources a, a1 and c, and the sources for those SourceBusinesses are "A" and "C".  Ideally, I would like to get the ["A", "C"] in one step.  Is this possible with the Django QuerySet API?

If it's not straightforward I can work around, just want to know if this can be done in one step.

EDIT: just to clarify, ["A", "C"] is the result I want, not the input.  So, not "which ResultBusiness come from SourceBusiness with source in [A,C]", but "for all ResultBusinesses which exist, what are the distinct possible values of their parent SourceBusiness.source"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
results = SourceBusiness.objects.filter(resultbusiness__isnull=False).distinct().values_list('source', flat=True)
```

Comment: this is the logic I'm looking for, but I get an error: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'resultbusiness' into field...
SourceBusiness to ResultBusiness is a one-to-many...how do I reference the ResultBusiness from SourceBusiness?

Comment: @vasek1 Haven't you set `related_name` for `sourcebusiness` field?

Comment: @vasek1 And what is the rest of error message, 'Choices are:' part?

Comment: didn't know about related_name, the query you suggested worked after I defined related_name.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
RB=ResultBusiness.objects.exclude(sourcebusiness__isnull=True).values_list('sourcebusiness__source',flat=True).distinct()
```

This is the one step thing.

**Assumption : The ForeignKey could be `null=True`**

Comment: @vasek1 You could try this. This is the one line reference that you might be looking for. (Initially, misinterpreted your question).

Comment: yep this works. I didn't know about the related_name field, but once I set that up the query worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @vasek1 Anytime. Learnt from your question as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Read the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects topic to know how to make such queries.

You should do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q = ResultBusiness.objects.filter(
   Q(sourcebusiness__source="A")|Q(sourcebusiness__source="C")
)
```